# Playback raw sound data in memory using MFC functions

Tags: windows, audio, mfc

I have an MFC based project that decodes some data and generates 16 bit 48000 Hz raw wav audio data

The program continuously generates wav audio data in real time

Are there any functions in MFC that will let me play back the audio data in the sound card? I have been googling around for a while and the consensus seems to be that MFC doesn't have this feature. I have also found [this tutorial](http://midi.teragonaudio.com/tech/highaud.htm) that shows how to playback a wav file using PlaySound() function, but it looks like it is only for wav files and even if it plays audio data in memory, that data has to be prepared in the form of a full wav file with all the header information, while I need to play back raw wav data generated in real time

I have also seen people suggest using Direct X, but I feel like something like this should be possible using basic windows library functions without having to use any other extra libraries. I also found [this tutorial](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/multimedia/audio/article.php/c8877/MFC-Multithreaded-Classes-for-Recording-Playing-and-Saving-WAV-Files.htm) for creating and reading wav files in an MFC based project, but it's not really clear how to use it to play raw wav data in memory. This tutorial uses waveOutOpen() function to playbakc the wav file, and it looks like this is probably what I need, but I cannot find a simple tutorial that shows how to use it.

How do I playback raw wav audio in memory in an MFC Dialog based project? I am looking for something where I can specify pointer to the wav data, number of samples, bits and sampling frequency and the function would playback the wav data for me. A basic working example such as generating a sinewave and playing it back will be appreciated. If directx is the only way to do this then that's fine as well.

Comment: It's not clear, why you consider DirectX (which ships with Windows since... forever) an extra library, but are fine with using MFC (a library that does not ship with Windows). At any rate, Windows' current audio infrastructure is exposed through the [WASAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/wasapi) API. It allows you to do what you are looking for, but it won't do it in a single function call. It's more like a hundred lines of code to set up.

Comment: @IInspectable then what is the most straight forward way to do this?

Comment: The link I posted above explains everything you need to know to use the API. [Rendering a Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/rendering-a-stream) is essentially a bare bones sample implementation for what you are trying to accomplish. The most straight forward way to implement this is to use C++ wrappers for the COM interfaces (like the [Compiler COM Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/compiler-com-support)). You need to understand C++ and COM to use it proficiently.